# Help interpreting residual vs fitted plot and normality (ANOVA on R)

Tags: anova, normality-assumption, assumptions, heteroscedasticity

I'm carrying out a statistical analysis on R using ANOVA and am not sure if the data meets the assumptions of normality of residuals or homogeneity of variance. 
My data :

[image: raw data:]

And my plots: 
[image: residual vs fit plot/homogeneity of variance plot]

[image: normality:]

Any help is really appreciated as I'm not sure how to interrupt these (as the res v fit does have a straight line, though diagonal, and it is fairly normal until the last few points).

Comment: Case #4 in the control group is at risk of being a typo. Is its thickness really 523 oder was that meant to be 253? I personally would accept your results but if you are uneasy about it -- it seems as if a Wilcoxon rank sum test could solve the problem without being brittle about small sample sizes etc.

Comment: @Bernhard unfortunately the 523 is correct (this was collated experimental data from a group practical, so some variance in observations). So with these results provided, would you say the assumptions of homogeneity of variance and normality are met? I understand that as it's data collected by a number of groups, the plot is less likely to be perfect, but wasn't sure if these plots would be acceptable in this case. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: It comes down to taste. To my taste these plots are acceptable. Meanwhile, I posted my statement in more detail as an answer.

Comment: OP has asked another question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432991/would-you-accept-this-normality-for-anova-asked-yesterday-but-data-revised-an indicating that these data have been found to contain errors. I consider my answer here conditional on the data posted above. Many of the points made by @Bernhard and myself are points of principle in any case for data loosely like these.

Answer (score 3):

I both agree and disagree with @Bernhard, and with respect one doesn't have to be "very picky" to disagree partially.

Agree: Sure, there is, given these data, a significant difference between control and mutant groups in general level. The fact that a Wilcoxon test supports analysis of variance on the original data underlines that this conclusion is robust to what summary statistic is the focus and quite what ideal conditions lie behind each test. (Many small discussions would be clarified at least a little if "ideal conditions" were the terminology, not "assumptions".)

Disagree: The original analysis of variance is far from the best way to work with these data. On elementary biological as well as statistical grounds, a positive response (presumably thickness can never be negative or even zero) with a skewed distribution and mild heteroscedasticity and possible high outliers is better analysed on logarithmic scale. The implication is that geometric means are better ways to summarize the data than means.  One kind of machinery is a generalized linear model with logarithmic link, which is easily done in R.

Here is one corresponding view of the data. Quantile plots are combined with median-quartile boxes. The other horizontal lines show geometric means. The data are not tamed by being viewed on logarithmic scale, but they are better behaved. I would name the units of measurement on my plot if I knew what they were. (I used Stata for the plot.)

[image]

Comment: +1 and also thank you for editing my answer. In case of multivariate analysis the log-normality assumption and combined with it the options to use linear regression is superior to my rank based approach. However, the biological nature of "thickness" does neither automatically imply lognormality nor does it exclude thicknesses of value $0$ (bad for geometric mean). The large value of >500 in one case in the control group does not go well with the "ideal condition" of log-normality. Critics might still argue it to be an influential and questionable data point, urging for parallel analysis w/o it

Comment: Sure; it is possible that we're measuring something that may not exist or equivalently may have thickness zero, but the data don't imply that. More crucially **_a generalized linear model with logarithmic link can be applied even if some of the data are not positive_**. My analysis isn't invalidated absolutely by some departure from lognormality; after all your stance is that ANOVA on original scale is not invalidated absolutely by some departure from normality. My suggestion is that just that analysis is better on logarithmic scale, not that any assumptions are thereby satisfied.

Comment: (ctd) The outlier is a bigger worry for your analysis than for mine.

Comment: Whilst thinking that all options displayed here are acceptable for that particular data set I agree that the analysis of variance is better on logarithmic scale. I raise the question, if analysis of variance is optimal for less than 20 observations in presence of an outlier. The outlier draws the to groups apart. Replace it with any of the more credible values of the control group and that will not influence the rank statistic. It will change the arithmetic as well as the geometric mean. Obviously, with larger samples, analysis of variance will get more robust against less ideal conditions.

Comment: I agree broadly, indeed exactly, but apart from what the OP tells us we are all speculating. The OP is telling us that the outlier is not especially suspect. We can add other ways of getting a handle on the uncertainty, e.g. bootstrapping.

Answer (score 2):

To put your data in a more R friendly format

```
control <- c(252.56, 283.36, 264.88, 523.4, 264.88, 247.19, 277.2, 237.16)
mutant <- c(150.92, 135.52, 215.6, 150.92, 147.84, 172.48, 138.6, 147.84)
```

A simple plot of the data makes clear, that there is clearly a distinction between the groups:

```
boxplot(control, mutant)
```

From looking at the plot everyone will believe you, that there is a statistical difference and nobody should get picky about a significant result:

[image]

Nothing in the world is ever perfectly normally distributed, few things are truly homoscedastic. Judging from your above plots I personally would accept your ANOVA results but someone very picky about it might start arguing. However, as I stated in my comment above, there is a simple means of clearing that once and for all:

```
> wilcox.test(control, mutant)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  control and mutant
W = 64, p-value = 0.0009148
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

(BTW: Even if `523.4` in case 4 was a typo and was truly `253.4`, that would not change the result of the rank sum statistic.)

Comment: (+1) Helpful. I note (as I have noted many times) that people often show box plots in support of ANOVA when ANOVA uses none of the quantities shown on box plots, but is based on means and variances or SDs.