# Would you accept this normality for ANOVA? (asked yesterday, but data revised and different graph)

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, normality-assumption, assumptions

I posted yesterday asking for help with ANOVA assumptions, however I discovered the data I was given had several incorrect values. This data fulfills the assumption of homogeneity of variance, and the plot for normality is shown below. [image]

This is just for a lab report so it's not that important that it's perfect (and i wouldn't expect it to be as it's from experimental data). Is it 'good enough' to say that the assumption of normality has been met? (and perhaps just mention the outliers?)

My lecturer also posted the plots of non-normal data below (with a post to help us decide on normality) and said he would also consider the first two normal. Is my plot similar enough to one of them to be considered normal (to him at least?). Of course, they have very different sample sizes so mine looks a bit different so i'm not sure. 
[image]

I'm really hoping this is acceptable as none of the transformations I've tried make it any better.

And as a last note, as ANOVA is apparently robust against violations of normality (when p is significantly above 0.05 - the significance threshold in this case), and my p value was 6.24x10^-7), would it be okay to accept anyway?

Sorry if this is very rambly, just quite lost and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The second one (middle top) would be somewhat concerning for an ANOVA because its skewness indicates p-values from the F statistic could be pretty far off and its shape suggests an important variable may have been omitted, or perhaps responses are heteroscedastic.  The point of this quick analysis is that normality of the residuals should be of little concern: there is much more to be learned from these plots.  In your case you will want to understand the two (modestly) high outliers and make sure your conclusions aren't overly sensitive to either of them.

Comment: The implied cross-reference is https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432760/help-interpreting-residual-vs-fitted-plot-and-normality-anova-on-r

Comment: @whuber thank you for replying. Could you explain what you mean by understanding the outliers? (Apologies, I'm very new to statistics and explaining them etc). The experiment was measuring cerebral cortex thickness in 8 different mutant and wildtype mice - so had measurements collected from 8 different groups. So the variation is likely due to inaccurate measurement. As the P value is so low (and i have boxplots included which reinforce the conclusion) would it be acceptable to say the assumption is met? Or would another test (like kruskal wallis) be better?

Comment: Would your conclusions remain the same if you removed either observation 8 or 11 (or both) from the data?  If not, your conclusions may only be due to inaccurate measurement.  That's an important sensitivity check.

Comment: @whuber thank you for your help! The conclusions would be the same (that there is a significant difference between the thicknesses of mutant and wildtype mouse cortexes, so i think that's fine

Comment: I suspect that's a stronger statement than you could make as a result of any consideration of normality of the residuals.